# CL_HTPP_CLIENT CODE 400 BAD REQUEST - ABAP

Tags: rest, post, abap

i am trying to Post a Json to a Web Service.
The connection is good , but Unfortunately the payload arrives empty to the other side.

The Variable Jsondata is not empty and is a string.

I dont know what is missing.  I have another Service to another api with a small json and works well.

```
Call Method cl_http_client=>create_by_url
  Exporting
    url                = url
  Importing
    client             = client
  Exceptions
    argument_not_found = 1
    plugin_not_active  = 2
    internal_error     = 3
  Others              = 4.
  If Sy-Subrc Ne 0.
    Raise Error_conexion_token.
  Else.
   .
    Data(Bearer) = 'Bearer' && | | && token.
    client->request->set_header_field(
     Exporting
       name  = 'Authorization'
       value = Bearer  ).
    client->request->set_header_field(
     Exporting
       Name  = 'Content-Type'
       Value = 'application/json; charset=utf-8' ).
 Call method client->request->set_cdata(
          Exporting data   = jsondata ).
        client->request->set_method( if_http_request=>co_request_method_post).

    Call Method client->send.
     If sy-subrc Ne 0.
      Raise Error_conexion_token.
     Else.
      Call Method client->receive
       Exceptions
        http_communication_failure = 1
        http_invalid_state         = 2
        http_processing_failed     = 3
       Others                      = 4.
       If sy-subrc Ne 0.
         Data(rc) = sy-subrc.
         client->get_last_error(
          Importing
           code    = zhcm_fdexperience=>codigo
           message = zhcm_fdexperience=>mensaje ).
         Case rc.
            When 1.
           Raise http_communication_failure.
            When 2.
           Raise http_invalid_state.
            When 3.
           Raise http_processing_failed.
         Endcase.
        Else.
         client->get_last_error(
           Importing
            code    = zhcm_fdexperience=>codigo
            message = zhcm_fdexperience=>mensaje ).
         Call method client->response->get_status( Importing code   = zhcm_fdexperience=>codigo
                                                              reason = zhcm_fdexperience=>mensaje ).

         If zhcm_fdexperience=>codigo Ne '200' Or zhcm_fdexperience=>codigo Ne '000' Or  zhcm_fdexperience=>codigo Ne '0'.
          Clear zhcm_fdexperience=>codigo.
          Clear zhcm_fdexperience=>mensaje.
          Data(Respuesta) = client->response->get_cdata( ).
         Else.
          Respuesta = client->response->get_cdata( ).
         Endif.
         Call method client->close.
```

An this is the json.

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "apiTipo": 1,
        "fechaHoraAccion": "07/09/2021 21:20:03",
        "nombreUsuarioSAP": "JUAN",
        "numeroPersonal": "00001127",
        "numeroPersonalREF": "sin informaciÃ³n",
        "tratamiento": "SeÃ±or",
        "apellidoPaterno": "letelier",
        "apellidoMaterno": "diaz",
        "nombre": "rodrigo",
        "sexo": "masculino",
        "fechaNacimiento": "29/05/1985",
        "estadoCivil": "Casado",
        "nacionalidad": "Argentina",
        "documentoIdentidad": "15902492-2",
        "sociedad": "SBIO",
        "divisionPersona": "CL01",
        "centroCosto": "sin informaciÃ³n",
        "subdivisionPersona": "sin informaciÃ³n",
        "calleNumero": "ladies nIght 3221",
        "ciudad": "san fernando",
        "region": "Libertador Bernardo",
        "pais": "Chile",
        "telefono": "717846",
        "claseContrato": "INDEFINIDO",
        "plazoPreavEmpresa": "22.5 HORAS SEMANALES",
        "reglaPlanJornadaColaborador": "BHADP201",
        "statGestionTiempo": "9 - Evaluacion",
        "indAdicTiempo": "NC",
        "claseConvenio": "Sin Negociacion",
        "areaConvenio": "No Sindicalizado",
        "grupoProfesional": "General",
        "subgrupoProfesional": "01",
        "claseCorreoPersonal": "adiazs@funk.com",
        "idSistema": "0016",
        "fechaInicio": "22/08/2021",
        "fechaFin": "31/12/9999"
    }
]
```

}

Note : I tested in postman and works well.

Comment: Can you test it just changing endpoint with requestcatcher.com?

Comment: You indicate it's `utf-8` but you use `set_cdata` which probably passes the JSON data as `utf-16`. If you convert your JSON data to `utf-8` and use `set_data`, it will be at least coherent. Worth trying. (NB: I don't say to use `charset=utf-16`, that might not work as there is also the byte endianness implied)

Comment: I tried to delete the utf-8 encodign header , unfortunatelly the same situation,

Comment: catch raw request with requestcatcher.com and try same payload with postman. Also check request size, maybe encoding different but you can see same payload.

Comment: how do you fill `jsondata` var? could it be it is empty on `set_header_field()` call, did you try to debug it?